# No more room when trying to add a building

Tags: marvel-avengers-academy

I'm trying to add a building but I have an error message.

It's telling me I have no more room? I do think I have enough space but its not allowing me to see.

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in a reddit thread that I created about the issue

> https://www.reddit.com/r/MarvelAvengersAcademy/wiki/buildings#wiki_avengers_stadium
>
> Stadium is huge, 7x10. You have to move things around or clear more
>   debris if you have some

So the error says exactly the right thing. Its just that Avengers Stadium is HUGE.

[image]